# Trying to reinstall MongoDB using Yum. First it says package is not installed, then it says already installed?

Tags: linux, mongodb

I have a problem with a service, it fails to start. I am trying to troubleshoot it by re-installing it. When I try to start or stop the service I see the following:

[image]

When I try uninstalling MongoDB using Yum I get this:

```
yum remove mongodb-org-2.6.1-2.x86_64 mongodb-org-server-2.6.1-2.x86_64 mongodb-org-    shell-2.6.1-2.x86_64 mongodb-org-mongos-2.6.1-2.x86_64 mongodb-org-tools-2.6.1-2.x86_64
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Setting up Remove Process
No Match for argument: mongodb-org-2.6.1-2.x86_64
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
* base: mirrors.usc.edu
* extras: mirror.ancl.hawaii.edu
* rpmforge: mirror.hmc.edu
* updates: repos.lax.quadranet.com
Package(s) mongodb-org-2.6.1-2.x86_64 available, but not installed.
No Match for argument: mongodb-org-server-2.6.1-2.x86_64
Package(s) mongodb-org-server-2.6.1-2.x86_64 available, but not installed.
No Match for argument: mongodb-org-shell-2.6.1-2.x86_64
Package(s) mongodb-org-shell-2.6.1-2.x86_64 available, but not installed.
No Match for argument: mongodb-org-mongos-2.6.1-2.x86_64
Package(s) mongodb-org-mongos-2.6.1-2.x86_64 available, but not installed.
No Match for argument: mongodb-org-tools-2.6.1-2.x86_64
Package(s) mongodb-org-tools-2.6.1-2.x86_64 available, but not installed.
No Packages marked for removal
```

Then when I uninstall again, the packages, it says:

```
yum remove mongodb-org-2.6.1-2.x86_64 mongodb-org-server-2.6.1-2.x86_64 mongodb-org-    shell-2.6.1-2.x86_64 mongodb-org-mongos-2.6.1-2.x86_64 mongodb-org-tools-2.6.1-2.x86_64
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Setting up Remove Process
No Match for argument: mongodb-org-2.6.1-2.x86_64
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.hmc.edu
 * extras: mirror.us.leaseweb.net
 * rpmforge: mirror.hmc.edu
 * updates: repos.lax.quadranet.com
Package(s) mongodb-org-2.6.1-2.x86_64 available, but not installed.
No Match for argument: mongodb-org-server-2.6.1-2.x86_64
Package(s) mongodb-org-server-2.6.1-2.x86_64 available, but not installed.
No Match for argument: mongodb-org-shell-2.6.1-2.x86_64
Package(s) mongodb-org-shell-2.6.1-2.x86_64 available, but not installed.
No Match for argument: mongodb-org-mongos-2.6.1-2.x86_64
Package(s) mongodb-org-mongos-2.6.1-2.x86_64 available, but not installed.
No Match for argument: mongodb-org-tools-2.6.1-2.x86_64
Package(s) mongodb-org-tools-2.6.1-2.x86_64 available, but not installed.
No Packages marked for removal
```

Answer (score 1):

Look closely at both sets of `yum` status messages; they are both 100% the same. They are both showing an attempt to uninstall and displaying messages like this:

> Package(s) mongodb-org-2.6.1-2.x86_64 available, but not installed.

All that means is the package `mongodb-org-2.6.1-2.x86_64` is available from the `yum` package repository, but is not actually installed on your system.

Have you just [tried reinstalling it after uninstalling](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat-centos-or-fedora-linux/)?

```
yum install mongodb-org-2.6.1-2.x86_64 mongodb-org-server-2.6.1-2.x86_64 mongodb-org-shell-2.6.1-2.x86_64 mongodb-org-mongos-2.6.1-2.x86_64 mongodb-org-tools-2.6.1-2.x86_64
```

Once you do that, the software should be reinstalled and you can just run this to start it:

```
sudo service mongod start
```

Answer (score 1):

try it

- Stop mongod service

  ```
  sudo service mongod stop
  ```
- Remove Package

  ```
  sudo yum erase $(rpm -qa | grep mongodb-org)
  ```
- Remove Data Directories

  ```
  sudo rm -r /var/log/mongodb
  sudo rm -r /var/lib/mongo
  ```

Create a /etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb-org-3.0.repo file so that you can install MongoDB directly, using yum

```
hold the following configuration for mongodb@3.0

[mongodb-org-3.0]
name=MongoDB Repository
baseurl=https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat/$releasever/mongodb-org/3.0  /x86_64/
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
```

then hit this one

```
 sudo yum install -y mongodb-org
```

You must configure SELinux to allow MongoDB to start on Red Hat Linux-based systems (Red Hat Enterprise Linux or CentOS Linux).

--Disable SELinux entirely by changing the SELINUX setting to disabled in /etc/selinux/config

```
 SELINUX=disabled
```

--Set SELinux to permissive mode in /etc/selinux/config by changing the SELINUX setting to permissive

```
 SELINUX=permissive
```

Enable access to the relevant ports (e.g. 27017) for SELinux if in enforcing mode. See Default MongoDB Port for more information on MongoDB’s default ports. For default settings, this can be accomplished by running

```
semanage port -a -t mongod_port_t -p tcp 27017
```

Comment: I have modified it for CentOS or RedHat, check it

Comment: hey dude, thank you for your effort. Unfortunately I have solved this problem years ago. I forgot the solution. I'm sorry I've wasted your time. Have an upvote anyway.